# How can I shift an array to the right in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, shift

I'm trying to implement a function for shifting an array of objects to the right of the array. All i found in the Internet is implementation of circular shifts but that is not what I'm looking for. I want to shift the elements to the right if theres actually empty space on its right.
suppose you created an array of object Packet, and its of size 10

```
Packet* a[] = { p4 , p3 , p2 , p1, null, null, null, null, null, null }
```

the shifting function would just shift everything to the right

```
{ null ,p4 , p3 , p2 , p1, null, null, null, null, null }
```

and in the case of having an element at the end of the array

```
{ p10, p9, p8, p7 ,p6 ,p5 ,p4 , p3 , p2 , p1}
```

the function just wouldn't shift anything.

```
 { p4 , p3 , p2 , p1, null, null, null, null, null, null }
```

my idea of implementation is to copy the array into a temp one,
erase everything on the original array, and then copy into it but starting from position [1] and not position [0]. but this doesn't seem very efficient.

any other ideas?

Comment: So if the last element is filled, don't shift? Why not just check that separately, followed by a quick `std::rotate`?

Comment: The title of the question says C, but the tag says C++.  The suggestion in chris' comment is C++ only.  Eduardo's answer below is probably a very bad idea in C++, and I'd consider it C only.  Please be specific about the language.

Comment: Yep, I agree with Nathan, use it only in C

Comment: Do you care what happens to pointers/references/iterators that point into the middle of the array, when you do the shift? That differs between the answers below, in some of them the value of the referand changes, in some of them the value of the referand doesn't change, and in one of them (at time of writing) the reference itself is invalidated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming the array has n elements:

```
if(a[n-1]==null){
   memmove(a+1, a, (n-1)*sizeof(Packet*));
   a[0]=null;
}
```

An alternative would be not to shift the elements of the array but the index you use to access it. Basically, what you want to do is add 1 modulo n.

Comment: `memcpy` has undefined behavior if the objects overlap (as is the case here).  You could use `memmove`, of course.  If he's using C++, however, `copy_backward` would be a better choice.

Comment: Good point, James. I have edited the solution to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: As @JamesKanze said memmove is safest and prevents the memcpy undefined behaviour by making a temporal copy first. Thanks to modify your answer.

Comment: @sgroh `memmove` doesn't make a copy.  What it does (usually) is compare the source and target address, and do the move from last to first if the target address is higher than the source address.  (In other words, it automatically chooses between `copy` and `copy_backwards`, according to whichever is most appropriate.)

Comment: Also: the question has an array of pointers, which can be copied with `memmove`. This answer uses `sizeof(Packet)` instead of `sizeof(Packet*)`, so it operates on an array of `Packet` objects, not an array of pointers. You *can* use `memmove` on user-defined objects in C++ if you really want to, but only if they're POD (in C++03) or trivially copyable (in C++11).

Comment: Good catch, Steve. I have edited the code, as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate the array from right-to-left, assigning element `n-1` to element `n`. When you reach the first element, assign `null` to it. (whatever that means)

Comment: If there needed to be a longer shift to the right, say 10 places, this loop could be applied multiple times. Is this still the best way to go about doing this if that were the case?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer in C++ is to use `std::vector`, in which case, it
becomes something as simple as:

```
if ( a.back() == NULL ) {
    a.insert( a.begin(), NULL );
    a.pop_back();
}
```

You might also consider `std::deque`, which would allow `push_front`,
instead of the `insert`.  For such small arrays of simple to copy
objects. the simplicity of `std::vector` generally wins out.

If you have to use a C style array, something like:

```
if ( *(end( a ) - 1) == NULL ) {
    std::copy_backwards( begin( a ), end( a ) - 1, end( a ) );
    a[0] = NULL;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: "the simplicity of std::vector generally wins out" - I wonder how often people re-test such rules of thumb. Unless you work out which is slower and choose that, someone will accuse you of premature optimization, but I'm mostly still convinced by http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm: `deque` has more functionality, so use that unless you need `vector` for contiguity or speed of `operator[]` / iteration. And despite being convinced by it, I still don't actually follow the advice, I generally use `vector` unless I'm going to use that functionality (as in this case insert at the front).

Comment: @SteveJessop In practice, I pretty much just use `std::vector` for everything, unless there are issues concerning lifetime of iterators (which can only be solved by `std::list`).  Or the profiler says otherwise.  In this case, it does depend on your habits or conventions, however.  One can easily argue that `deque` is more natural, because you want a `push_front`.  The "generally wins out" is really relative to my habits (where `std::deque` means that there are special constraints).

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do this a lot (and the array is not small), consider using [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), as it allows efficient insertion and removal at both ends. A shift to right for `N` places can then be replaced with popping `N` nulls from the back and pushing `N` nulls at the front. You can use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) for that, too.

Answer (score 2):

For any container (including raw array) for POD and non POD types, use the following:

```
template <class Iterator, class Distance>
void shiftRight(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Distance dist)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    Iterator newBegin = begin, oldEnd = end;
    std::advance(newBegin, dist);
    std::advance(oldEnd, -dist);
    std::copy_backward(begin, oldEnd, end);
    std::fill(begin, newBegin, value_type());
}
```

It is for POD and nonPOD types since `copy_backward` takes care of the value category and if it is POD then it uses `memmove` (at least in std library used by gcc).

`std::advance` for random access iterator is using simple addition/subtraction.

`std::fill` also takes care of PODness like `std::copy*`.

`value_type()` for pointer types is just NULL, for bool false, for integral types 0 and so on.

Usage for arrays:

```
  int* a[] = { 0, new int(1), new int(2), 0, 0, new int(3) };

  std::for_each(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a), [](int* a) { !a ? (std::cout << "null\n") : (std::cout << *a << "\n"); });

  shiftRight(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a), 3);
  std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------\n";

  std::for_each(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a), [](int* a) { !a ? (std::cout << "null\n") : (std::cout << *a << "\n"); });
```

Output as expected:

```
null
1
2
null
null
3
-----------------------------------------------------
null
null
null
null
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a linked list which will allow you to shift/unshift or push/pop elements (the space will be freed in this case).

What's wrong with Circular way of doing it? its quite efficient. Eg.:

```
bool insert(Packet *queue[], int *rear, int front, Packet *value)
{
  int tmp = (*rear+1) % MAX;
  if (tmp == front) 
    return false;

  *rear = tmp;
  queue[*rear] = value;
  return true;
}

bool delete(Packet *queue[], int rear, int *front, Packet **value) 
{
  if (*front == rear) 
    return false;

  *front = (*front+1) % MAX;
  *value = queue[*front];
  return true;
}
```

Comment: My understanding was that the question is about C only. In C++ there are easier solutions (see above posts)

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, we have [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

```
int [] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::rotate(
    std::begin(values),
    std::next(std::begin(values)), // the new 'top'
    std::end(values));
*std::rbegin(values) = 0;

assert(values[0] == 2);
assert(values[1] == 3);
assert(values[2] == 4);
assert(values[3] == 5);
assert(values[4] == 0);
```